# WPF-MVVM: using ICollectionView for Searching a ListBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox of Items and a Search TextBox and Search Button, i want to enter the search text in the TextBox and Click Search Button so the ListBox highlight that item and get it on screen (for lengthy list).
Is it possible to do this using ICollectionView? and if not possible how to implement this scenario.
Note: after googling i found all samples talking about Filtering but i need searching.
Thanks for bearing with us.

Comment: Yes, it's possible and filtering on the collection view is a preferred solution.  Although it says 'Filtering', you can substitute the words 'Search and Select' for it.

Comment: @GarryVass i know the steps for filtering using ICollectionView how to modify it for searching and highlighting the required item

Comment: The highlighting is on the visual side and its implementation can *use* the ICollectionView, but the visuals will need templating or other implementations.  Two different animals type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing a Prism Behavior:

```
public class AutoScrollingBehavior:Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        var itemsSource = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as ICollectionView;

        if (itemsSource == null)
            return;

        itemsSource.CurrentChanged += ItemsSourceCurrentChanged;
    }

    void ItemsSourceCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(((ICollectionView)sender).CurrentItem);
        AssociatedObject.Focus();
    }
}
```

Another approach is listening to ListBox.SelectionChanged instead of ICollectionView.CurrentChanged.

```
public class AutoScrollingBehavior:Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count <= 0)
            return;
        AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(e.AddedItems[0]);
        AssociatedObject.Focus();
    }
}
```

On Xaml:

```
    <ScrollViewer Height="200">
        <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NamesView}" SelectionMode="Single"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:AutoScrollingBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Inside searching command, you set `NamesView.MoveCurrentTo(foundItem)`. However this approach will only scroll to the edge, instead of center, might you expected. If you want it to scroll to the center, you might need `ItemContainerGenerator`.

In your view model who holds the ICollectionView:

```
private string _searchText;

    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set
        {
            _searchText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SearchText");
        }
    }

    private ICommand _searchCommand;

    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get { return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new DelegateCommand(Search)); }
    }

    private void Search()
    {
        var item = _names.FirstOrDefault(name => name == SearchText);
        if (item == null) return;

        NamesView.MoveCurrentTo(item);
    }
```

On Xaml, bind TextBox.Text to SearchText and bind search button's Command to SearchCommand.

Hope it can help.

Comment: It is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. I edit the answer to show you how to bind text.

Comment: var item = _names.FirstOrDefault(name => name == SearchText);
item always null and for (name => name == SearchText) LHS is an object and RHS is a string

Comment: This is a just an example to tell you the way to solve the problem. It might be much more complex in real world. For example, the LHS is an object, then what you should do? Follow the business logic. If you are looking for person by his first name, then use _persons.FirstOrDefault(person => person.Firstname == SearchText), and so on.

Comment: ok i fixed this point but the problem is nothing happen, the Search method is called but the searched list box item not highlighted or scrolled to

Comment: Is the item after LINQ is null? Is the event handler in behavior called?